# Laravel 10 how to use links method for a paginated relation in view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

i use paginate method for reviews (that is a relation of Book model) but i can't use links method to navigate between pages.

my code :

```
Book::with([
            'reviews' => fn($query)=> $query->latest()->paginate(5)
        ])->findOrFail($id)
```

when i use links method in my view i get below error:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Book::links()

Comment: Have you tried `$book->reviews->links()`? You're paginating the relationship, not the `$book` instance. That all being said, I'm not sure if you _can_ paginate a relationship like that (or at least, I haven't tried it). You might need to separate it to a separate query, like `$book = Book::findOrFail($id); $reviews = $book->reviews()->latest()->paginate(5);`, then you'd do `$reviews->links()` in your `.blade.php`.

Comment: i tried `$book->reviews->links()` but it didn't work as well. separating the queries is the best option i think. thanks for answer @TimLewis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

separating the queries is the best option i think, like:

```
$book = Book::findOrFail($id); 
$reviews = $book->reviews()->latest()- 
>paginate(5);
```

then do `$reviews->links()` in .blade.php.

thanks to Tim Lewis for answer